# MATLAB: How to change pixel values after using VideoReader

Tags: image, matlab, video

I'm trying to read a video file using VideoReader and change some pixel values and save it back to the video file. I can easily change the matrix values but how do I save it back into the video file?

```
obj = VideoReader('DemoClip.asf');
imageData = read(obj);
imageData(17,32,:) = 65;
```

Comment: The [tag:processing] tag should only be used for questions about the Processing language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do it using [videoWriter](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videowriter-class.html?searchHighlight=videowriter). The code is commented; if something is unclear please ask. I used the demo xylophone.mp4 file from Mathworks.

```
clear
clc
close all

xyloObj = VideoReader('xylophone.mp4');

imageData = read(xyloObj);

%// Open writer object
writerObj = VideoWriter('NewVideo.avi');
open(writerObj);

%// Show 1st frame
hIm = imshow(imageData(:,:,:,1));
for k = 1:size(imageData,4)

    %// Change pixel values
    imageData(1:200,1:200,:,k) = uint8(0);

    %// Refresh cdata property. Faster than calling repetitevely imshow
    set(hIm,'CData',imageData(:,:,:,k));

    drawnow
    frame = getframe;
    %// Write to video file
    writeVideo(writerObj,frame);

end

close(writerObj);
```

Sample frame of the resulting video:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I have another question. I noticed that VideoWriter only lets you create a .avi file. Is it possible to make it into another type? Such as .asf?

Comment: VideoWriter allows you to write Motion JPEG AVI, Uncompressed AVI, Motion JPEG 2000 and MPEG-4/H.264. See the VideoWriter doc for details.